# How to pass multiple argument in a get method in Angular?

Tags: angularjs-directive, angular10

I need to pass 3 arguments in get method but the issue is get method is expecting 1-2 arguments . How can it resolve.?

Answer (score 0):

```
const params = new HttpParams()
   .set('p1', 'one!')
   .set('para2', "two")
   .set('para3', "three");
```

Then

```
this.httpClient.get<any>(yoururl,{params}) // {params} short form of {params:params}
```